# ReferenceError: Promise is not defined OnsenUI

Tags: node.js, onsen-ui, monaca

So i just installed monaca by following [this](https://onsen.io/getting-started.html) doc from onsen website. But when i do the second step i always get this error:

```
[ReferenceError: Promise is not defined]
```

Tried everything on the internet but it seems like all the question is not relevant to onsen ui. So i decided to ask.

Comment: Looks like you are using an old version of Node.js. Can you try updating to a newer version?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - the problem doesn't seem to come from Onsen UI.

Most likely during the `monaca create` command the code is trying to use native promises, but wasn't able to find them.

Make sure that you have node version which is at least `0.12` and you should be fine.